# homestead laravel 5 : link Download file from storage

Tags: php, download, laravel-5.1

i am need hint link to download upload file, currently i am following this [answer](https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-file-upload-storage-download/)
here is my code

Routes file :

```
Route::get('getDownload/{remind_letter}',
            ['as'=>'downloadData',
            'uses'=>'DockController@getDownload']);
```

Controller File :

```
  public function getDownload($remind_letter)
{

    $download = Dock::where('remind_letter','=',$remind_letter)->firstOrFail();
    $file =Storage::disk('local')->get($download->remind_letter);
    return (new response($file))->header('Content-Type', $entry->m1);
}
```

result file

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label class="col-sm-7">Remind Letter :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="remind_letter" value="{{$getData->remind_letter}}">                    
                    </div>
                    <div><a href="{{ route('downloadData',$getData->remind_letter) }}">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Download</button></a></div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

and the result link `dock.start/star/getDownload/home/vagrant/Code/dock/storage/app/25/JTK/2015/Renewal License Kaspersky/Moonarch Security/tmp/phpQaGzoD.pdf`

but the link is always show up error 404 and i can't download file

FYI when upload file i am using `storage_path()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it fix, i am wrong logic, when upload file it should using `getFilename()` function, `$entry->filename = $filename->getFilename().$extension;`